# Build a social network & organization database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, social-networking

I'm doing a PhD in political science and plan to collect datas on several organizations and do some social network analysis.
I'm new to database building and management, and I'd like to know what tool (LibreOffice Base, MySql, etc.) would be the best for me.
In this database, I would have a list of organizations (approximately 200) with various attributes and files attached, a list of individuals working in/with one or several of these organizations, a list of coalitions linking different organizations, a list of events where some organizations/individuals are, etc.

I'm starting from scrap, what do you think would be the best way to build this database ? I tried with LibreOffice Base and started to create different tables (organizations, individuals, etc.) but I'm not sure it will fit my needs.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score -1):

I think you should look at a graph database engine like [Neo4J](http://neo4j.com/) for this use case.

With a graph DB, one could store entities (such as organizations in your case) and relationships between them in the form of nodes and edges. By having your data stored this way, you can easily interrogate your data for insights that might not be easily done using standard relational data systems.

[Free ebook describing the need for graph storage and the common problems solved by such a datastore](http://graphdatabases.com/)

Say, that you wish to store information about organizations, individuals working for those organizations, their job roles etc. You can do this by creating Nodes and relationships like the following:

```
(Person:"Joe Bloggs")-[:WORKS_AT]->(Organization: Google)
(Person:"Joe Bloggs")-[:WORKS_AS]->(JobRole: "Software Developer")
```

The above describes a person called Joe Bloggs that works for Google as a software developer. You can use Ciper query language (official language used for querying Neo4j) to get all software developers working for google.

Comment: And the reason why "graph" database is better than relational one - that wasn't mentioned? Your answer looks exactly like "I am using Neo4J so I will go and recommend it". Be objective and provide a **reason** why tool A instead of tool B. As it stands, relational database **is** the tool for the job. Why would graph db the tool? What's so special about it that a relational one can't do? Please, just don't mention performance because all those tests are a huge bs designed to attract people.

Comment: You are correct in that I might not have described in detail why the OP should look at Graph databases over relational DBs. However, the question itself is somewhat broad and I've provided a link to literature that goes in to detail as to why graph databases are better suited for social network related use cases. Also, yes, the performance IS a huge reason why one might make the switch. We've made the switch in our production systems and have gained significant performance improvements over our previous relational system that depended heavily on caching de-normalised data

Comment: So, how should anyone trust that what you're saying is a fact? You stated that you gained performance, so I should believe you that you've used relational system properly, along with configuration and actual data structure / queries? Where's the undoubted proof of your statements? This is exactly why such statements are dangerous. I've seen so many companies only this week who were shocked what a relational system does **once configured and used by a person who knows SQL**. I'm always the one who says right tool for the job. A relational database is such a tool.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that ! Performance is not really an important criteria for me, since I have a limited number of nodes and data.
And Mjh, what would be the benefits of a relational database in my case ?

Comment: It looks pretty interesting, I'm looking at the book and the manual. But I can't find the answer to this question: is it possible to export relationships as an edge list or a social network matrix (0 & 1) so you can import it in SNA softwares such as Pajek or R ?

Comment: I imagine that it may involve a bit of DIY since ready made tools are not very common. This shouldn't be too hard though. It should be relatively simple to write a script that would iterate over the result set from Neo4J and transpose them in to some format that these applications support. This article that explains how to transpose a resultset to CSV http://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/